# Trying to setState of buttons which is clicked but State of previously clicked buttons is unchanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I was trying to change images when I clicked but, when I clicked previously clicked buttons remains same as red.
I tried to make only one button to be red at a time and others should be black (like radio buttons).

This is my code, please help.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import redlogo  from "./redlogo.png";
import blacklogo  from "./blacklogo.png";

class   App  extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {src:blacklogo};
  }

  changeImageSource(index,event) {
    console.log('button is clicked at index ' + index)
    event.target.src = redlogo;
  }

  render() {
    let tracks = ["button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4", "button 5", "button 6 ", "button 7", "button 8", "button 9",];
    
    return( 
        <div className="scrollmenu" id="scrolldiv"  >
          { console.log(tracks)}
          {tracks.map((item,index)=>
                  <button id={index} key={index}
                   onClick={this.changeImageSource.bind(this,index)}
                  > 
                    <figure>
                      <img  className='img' src={this.state.src} />
                      <figcaption>{item}</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                  </button>   
              )}
       </div>
       )
      }
  }
export default  App ;
```

Comment: I was trying that when one button is clicked, others should reset. [link](https://github.com/gd10/reactjs_buttons-/blob/master/Screenshot%20from%202018-01-30%2009-51-25.png)

Comment: below I have given corrected code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently doesn't work since you don't track which index should be black and which index should be red. This can be resolved by tracking the index in the state instead of the source. Here's one way to do it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedIndex: null};
}

changeImageSource(event) {
  this.setState({selectedIndex: event.target.name})
}

render() {
  let tracks = ["button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4", "button 5", "button 6 ", "button 7", "button 8", "button 9",];

return( 
    <div className="scrollmenu" id="scrolldiv"  >
      { console.log(tracks)}
      {tracks.map((item,index)=>
              <button id={index} key={index} name={index} onClick={this.changeImageSource} > 
                <figure>
                  <img  className='img' src={index === this.state.selectedIndex ? redlogo : blacklogo} />
                  <figcaption>{item}</figcaption>
                </figure>
              </button>   
          )}
   </div>
   )
  }
```

}

Now how in the render's `.map` we now make the comparison for which logo should show for each picture: `src={index === this.state.selectedIndex ? redlogo : blacklogo}`. Since only one index can be selected, then this condition will ensure the redlogo appears only once and the rest are black.

Also the `changeImgSource` function now updates the `selectedIndex` instead of the image source, which had no relationship to relate it to an index so you would see multiple red logos.

Comment: Thanks Alexei Darmin,it worked. I only did few changes in it, without using `name={index}` 1) `<button id={index} key={index} name={index} onClick={this.changeImageSource.bind(this,index)} > `  , 2)  `changeImageSource(index,event) {  this.setState({ selectedIndex: index }) }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has major logical error. What i understand from your question is that you want only 1 button to be red at a time. If that is so than you can assign a state that saves button index that needs to be red at current moment. Inside constructor : `this.state = {red_btn : null}`.
Than on any button click Inside changeImageSource function : `this.setState({red_btn : index})`.
With that logical setup you can render image src attribute with : `src={this.state.red_btn == index ? "./red_logo.png" : "./black_logo.png"}`

That all being said even your current code have few things that needs corrections. This is only for you better understanding:
If you are passing `this.state.src` in image src attribute than on button click handler you have to `this.setState({src: image_url})`.

Your event handler is called on button click so inside that event handler (i.e. changeImageSource function) event.target is not you image but button and you are setting src on that button.